# What does TPB-2 and IC mean in this LAN Single Line Diagram?

Tags: line, diagram, lan

Since me and my colleagues can't figure this one out and was proposed to us as LAN Single Line Diagram, we've been asking other people and searching in the Internet what TPB and IC stand for and what they actually are. [image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that it was a Telephone Box. Sigh.